# A more common word for the noun "effectuator"

Tags: synonyms

I want to use the noun "effectuator" to denote an object that delivers the final effect which was produced by a whole chain of mechanisms. For example, a bullet shot out of a gun is an effectuator of a whole system of forces (person pointing the gun, the mechanics of the gun allowing it to fire bullets, etc.). However, the noun "effectuator" seems to exist in few dictionaries.

Is there a more common word for the noun "effectuator"?

Comment: It's not a single word, but I've often heard "*last link in the chain*" used in this sense; also relevant are the adjectives "*ultimate*" and "*immediate*" (as in the "*immediate cause*").

Comment: Not perhaps very _common_, but how about _proximate cause_?

Comment: Perhaps, the *catalyst*?

Comment: @Matt, "*proximate cause*" means "*not immediate cause*"; in other words, the hammer striking the pin is a proximate cause of the bullet's velocity, as is the finger pulling the trigger, but the gas pressure in the barrel is the immediate cause.

Comment: @DanBron [This Wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximate_and_ultimate_causation) states "A proximate cause is an event which is closest to, or immediately responsible for causing, some observed result." That agrees with Merriam-Webster's [definition for "proximate"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proximate): "immediately preceding or following (as in a chain of events, causes, or effects)".

Comment: @MattGutting, huh. I sit corrected.  Thanks for that!

Comment: Thanks, these are all helpful. But part of the attractiveness of "effectuator" is that it's a 1-word noun...

Comment: You might be attracted by *effectuator* being a single word. Or you might be interested in actually communicating. Your choice. ;-) *Proximate cause* is well understood by many (most?) readers. *Effectuator* is not.

Comment: Does "trigger" work?

Comment: @Ste 'trigger' would correspond to the distal cause, the initiator or first in the sequence. The OP is looking for the _last_ in the sequence. Well, from the items mentioned the literal trigger is somewhere in the middle of things.

Comment: @Mitch good point, I was thinking of a series of triggers.  I will think harder.

Comment: Also despite 'effectuator' not being (much of) a word, whatever it is it doesn't sound like it means what you want it to mean.

Comment: Hmmm. Guns don't kill people. Bullets kill people. (*How to say that in one word?*)... What was the cause of death? ... His heart stopped beating.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your bullet example, it seems like you may be looking for the word *culmination*, meaning "the end or  final result of something" according to the Merriam-Webster dictionary.

In fact, based on the same example, you are misusing the word *effectuator*, which refers to the cause of something, not its result.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a true synonym for effectuator, but actor or agent may be useful, an actor being *something that acts*, and an agent being *something that acts on behalf of another*.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen effectuator, however there is 
[effector](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=effector&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=).

> S: (n) effecter, effector (one who brings about a result or event; one who accomplishes a purpose)

[Executor](http://gcide.gnu.org.ua/?q=executor&define=Define&strategy=.) has a similar meaning, however, I have not seen it applied to non-persons.

> Executor (?), n. [L. executor, exsecutor: cf. F. exécuteur.  Cf. Executer.]
>   1. One who executes or performs; a doer; as, “an executor of baseness”.  Shak.
>   [1913 Webster]

Answer (score 0):

### The Catalyst

> : a person or event that quickly causes change or action

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catalyst

> The recent removal of characters from The Simpsons may just be the catalyst that terminates the show entirely